# How to deploy a Suave.IO project with Heroku

Tags: heroku, f#, suave

This is my first time using heroku and I'm having some troubles deploying my small Suave web app. After reviewing the docs [here](https://suave.io/heroku.html), I understand that I need to set up a Procfile so that heroku knows how to run my application.

Here's a picture of my basic file structure:

[image: File structure]

And my Procfile contains only a single line:

```
web: mono /bin/Debug/SuaveTest.exe
```

After pushing these files to heroku, I get an error when trying to view the application.

[image]

I'm obviously doing something wrong here and I definitely would appreciate any and all help to get this running.

**EDIT**

I've changed my project settings to target .NET 4.5 instead of 4.5.1. This removed some warnings during my build. After changing my Procfile to the following :

`web: mono bin/Release/SuaveTest.exe`

I'm still receiving the same application error when visiting the site, even though the build says everything went well. I am suspicious that the root cause of all my issues is because heroku is unable to discover what process types I'm using in my project (which you can see below).

```
remote: Build succeeded.
remote:      0 Warning(s) 
remote:      0 Error(s)
remote: 
remote: Time Elapsed 00:00:04.4188560
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> (none)
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 69.2M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v15
```

Comment: I think you should drop the leading slash, and change to release `web: mono bin/Release/SuaveTest.exe`. For more information, check your logs

Comment: @xuanduc987 I've applied your edits, check out my updated question for those results. Am I on the right track?

Comment: If you put your Procfile at the root of your repo, then process type should be discovered by Heroku.
I'm out of idea here, maybe contact heroku support for help